# .html() element not changing javascript value onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added an onlick attribute to .html() element, however it is not functioning as intended and does not change a JavaScript value. When clicked on "back", it is supposed to go back to the "initial" line, yet it does not, I can only move between elements one-three.

Keep in mind that this is a snippet from a complex three.js program, hence the animate() function, which is being continuously called.

Thanks!

```js
var currentClicked=-1;
 
animate();
 
function next(input){
  currentClicked=input;
  console.log(currentClicked);
  return text(currentClicked);
}
 
function returnBack(){
  console.log("event catched");
  currentClicked=-1;
  return text(currentClicked);
}
    
function text(currentClicked_){ 
  var back="<h7 id='goBackButton' onclick='returnBack()'>Back.</h7>";
  $(document).ready(function(){
    switch(currentClicked_){
      case -1:
        $(".CurrentText").html(" <p >initial</p> ");
        break;
      case 0:
        $(".CurrentText").html("<p>[01] </p> "+back);
        break;
      case 1:
        $(".CurrentText").html(" <p>[02]<p/>"+back);
        break;
      case 2:
        $(".CurrentText").html("<p>[03] </p>"+back);
        break;
      default:
        $(".CurrentText").html("<p>default </p>"); 
        break;
    }
  });
}
 
 
function animate() {
  //console.log(currentClicked);
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  text(currentClicked);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p onclick="next(0)">element one</p>
<p onclick="next(1)">element two</p>
<p onclick="next(2)">element three</p>

<div class="CurrentText"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to rebuild DOM element ("Back button") each time the user does some action. Also I recommend to completely split js and html and not to set handlers via `onclick` attribute, but via `.on()`. So I would suggest following approach:

```
<p id="e1">element one</p>
<p id="e2">element two</p>
<p id="e3">element three</p>
<p id="back" style="display: none;">back</p>

<div class="CurrentText"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#e1').on('click', function() { next(1); });
  $('#e2').on('click', function() { next(2); });
  $('#e3').on('click', function() { next(3); });
  $('#back').on('click', function() { back(); });

  var current = -1;
  var initial = -1;

  function back() {
    current = initial;
    outputIndex();
    $('#back').hide();
  }

  function next(index) {
    current = index;
    outputIndex();
    $('#back').show();
  }

  function outputIndex() {
    $('.CurrentText').html(current);
  }

  outputIndex(); // or don't call it if you don't want to output initial value on start

});    
</script>
```

Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/H2L1DRXTomlhWJeDR8sx?p=preview) demo.

Answer (score 0):

you have three issues :

1- there is no element called `h7` the headings is from `h1` to `h6` only.

2- your function `animate` is called inside itself (recursive function) here

```
function animate() {
 console.log(currentClicked);
 //requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 text(currentClicked);
}
```

which cause browser crashing.

3- when you are dealing with dynamically created elements you would better use `body` as selector and bind the event to the selector you need like:

```
$('body').on('click','h6',returnBack)
```

```js
var currentClicked=-1;
 
animate();
 
function next(input){
  currentClicked=input;
  console.log(currentClicked);
  return text(currentClicked);
}
 
function returnBack(){
  console.log("event catched");
  currentClicked=-1;
  //return text(currentClicked);
}
$('body').on('click','h6',returnBack)
function text(currentClicked_){ 
  var back="<h6 id='goBackButton' >Back.</h6>";
  $(document).ready(function(){
    switch(currentClicked_){
      case -1:
        $(".CurrentText").html(" <p >initial</p> ");
        break;
      case 0:
        $(".CurrentText").html("<p>[01] </p> "+back);
        break;
      case 1:
        $(".CurrentText").html(" <p>[02]<p/>"+back);
        break;
      case 2:
        $(".CurrentText").html("<p>[03] </p>"+back);
        break;
      default:
        $(".CurrentText").html("<p>default </p>"); 
        break;
    }
  });
}
 
 
function animate() {
  console.log(currentClicked);
  //requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  text(currentClicked);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p onclick="next(0)">element one</p>
<p onclick="next(1)">element two</p>
<p onclick="next(2)">element three</p>

<div class="CurrentText"></div>
```